# The method 'bloc' isn't defined for the type 'BuildContext'

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, flutter-bloc

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final appBar = AppBar(
      title: Text(
        "Romantic Comedy",
      ),
      actions: [
        IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.search),
          onPressed: () {
            showSearch(
                context: context,
                delegate: MaterialSearch(_pagingController.itemList));
          },
        ),
      ],
    );

    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        appBar: appBar,
        body: BlocConsumer<MovieBloc, MovieState>(
            listener: (context, movieState) {

            },
            builder: (context, movieState) {
              if (movieState is MovieSuccessState) {
                movieBloc.movies.addAll(movieState.movies);
              }
              return GridView.builder(
                  controller: _scrollController
                    ..addListener(() {
                      if (_scrollController.offset ==
                          _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent) {
                        context.bloc<MovieBloc>()
                          ..isFetching = true
                          ..add(Fetch());
                      }
                    }),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 12.0, right: 12.0),
                  gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                      crossAxisCount: 3),
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) => MovieTile(_movies[index]));
            }));
  }
```

Comment: What version of `flutter_bloc` you are using?
after `v6.1.0` both `context.bloc` and `context.repository` are deprecated in favor of `context.read` and `context.watch`
checkout the [migration guide](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/migration?id=v610)

Comment: flutter_bloc: ^7.0.1

Comment: Ok @Adnan alshami you can give this as an answer and I'll mark it as the right answer.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

After `flutter_bloc v6.1.0`,

Both `context.bloc` and `context.repository` are deprecated
and replaced with `context.read` and `context.watch`.

Checkout the [migration guide](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/migration?id=v610) for more information.

Comment: perfect solution for me , big thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think that the below code that you used means that will use bloc from the parent widget defined with `BlocProvider`. But because it seems that you have a bloc instance in this widget you just use that instance.

```
// with extensions
context.bloc<BlocA>();

// without extensions
BlocProvider.of<BlocA>(context)
```

Because you used `movieBloc` at the `MovieSuccessState` state,
I think you can just refer `isFetching` and `add` method using `movieBloc` instead of `context.bloc<MovieBloc>()`.

```
return GridView.builder(
                  controller: _scrollController
                    ..addListener(() {
                      if (_scrollController.offset ==
                          _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent) {
                        //context.bloc<MovieBloc>()
                        //  ..isFetching = true
                        //  ..add(Fetch());
                        movieBloc.isFetching = true;
                        movieBloc.add(Fetch());
                      }
                    }),
```

Comment: Sorry , I need to access bloc from parent

Comment: Through 'movieBloc.movies.addAll(movieState.movies);', I think that there is a bloc instance in this widget already. With your bloc version and Adnan Alshami's comment, it seems that you need to migrate.